# Google Scripts - Add multiple guests to a calendar event from a single cell in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I have a Google spreadsheet that we're using to deliver single calendar events to multiple accounts. Code below. I am getting an "Invalid argument" error for .addguest whenever there is more than one email address in the cell I'm trying to pull from (separated by commas).

The code below will pull correctly if only one account is in the cell, but not if multiple accounts are listed with commas in that same cell.

All ideas appreciated.

Thank you!

--Drew

```
 function onOpen() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Add Events to Google Calendar", functionName: "scheduleClass"}];
   s.addMenu("Google Calendar Functions", menuEntries);
 }

function scheduleClass(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("primary@group.calendar.google.com");

  var title = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
  var startTime = sheet.getRange('E2:E').getValues();
  var endTime = sheet.getRange('F2:F').getValues();
  var theDescription = sheet.getRange('G2:G').getValues();
  var theLocation = sheet.getRange('H2:H').getValues();
  var theGuests = sheet.getRange('K2:K').getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < title.length+1; i++){
    if(title[i][0] != ""){
      calendar.createEvent(title[i][0], startTime[i][0], endTime[i][0]).addGuest(theGuests[i][0]).setLocation(theLocation[i][0]).setDescription(theDescription[i][0]);

    }
  }
}

function toString(value){
  var newString = "" + value;
  return newString;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to specify ranges `A2:A` because you will get nulls in the data from sheet.getLastRow() all the way down to maxRows.  It would be better to use this instead (2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1)  ... actually you can leave the last one off to but I never do just to be clear.  I'm not saying that this is the solution to your problem.  I just saying that it is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper. I have almost no coding experience, so pardon my ignorance here: when you write (2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1), does this mean I rewrite that first variable
`var title = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
var startTime = sheet.getRange(5,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();`
where that first number equals the column?

Comment: I don't understand your question but what I'm saying is that rather than doing this `var title = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues();`  do this instead `var title = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();`

Comment: The third parameter is number of rows so since you started 2 at there are sheet.getLastRow()-1 rows to the bottom of data.

Comment: Ah. My question is how the numbers within the parentheses relate to the range. 
So, I understand that `('A2:A')` corresponds to `(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1)`. What I don't understand is what `('E2:E')` will look like. That is, I don't know what the `2,1` stands for. Again, thank you for your responses, @Cooper. Much, much appreciated. And, any ideas about the lack of being able to pull multiple email addresses in one cell with .addguest?

Comment: `sheet.getRange(starting row, starting column,number of rows, number of columns)`  [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: you could have got all of your data at one time by using `var data=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,11);`

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper! I've updated the variables to read like this: `var title = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var startTime = sheet.getRange(2,5,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var endTime = sheet.getRange(2,6,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var theDescription = sheet.getRange(2,7,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var theLocation = sheet.getRange(2,8,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var theGuests = sheet.getRange(2,11,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();` Now I'm back to getting the same "Invalid argument: email1@dot.com, email2@dot.com"

Comment: Not that you would necessarily want to do this but I would write your function like this `function scheduleClass(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("primary@group.calendar.google.com");
  var data=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,11).getValues();
  data.forEach(function(r,i){if(r[0]!=""){calendar.createEvent(r[0], r[4], r[5]).addGuest(r[10]).setLocation(r[7]).setDescription(r[6]);}});
}`  It's a little bit harder to debug in the script editor but once you have it running you can roll all up into a nice little package.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't really helped you with your problem.  All I can do is to suggest that you debug it one line at a time until you figure it out. That's what I would do.

Comment: That's a much more elegant solution, @Cooper. I'll give it a try. What portion of that code will get me around the roadblock I'm running into - namely that `.addGuest(theGuests[i][0])` doesn't pull the comma-separated list of people in that cell and add them as guests in the event?

Comment: I looked at the addGuest method and I'm left with the impression that you have add them one at a time.

Comment: I'd guess that you could probably add more that one at a time with the Advanced Calendar API but I don't actually know that. [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addGuest(String))

Comment: You've spent a lot of time with me on this issue, @Cooper. I appreciate the digging. If I find an answer to this, I'll definitely add it here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to create the calendar events with the multiple guests.

  - In your situation, the value of column "K" is like `sample1@gmail.com,sample2@gmail.com` which is separated by `,`.
  - The values of columns "A", "E", "F", "G", "H" and "K" in the active sheet are title, start time, end time, description, location and guests, respectively.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- When the guests are separated by `,`, you can retrieve each email using `split()`. And they can be added with `addGuest(email)`.
- In your script, an error occurs at the loop by `title.length+1` of `for(var i = 0; i < title.length+1; i++){`.
- When you retrieve the values from the data range of "A2:K#", the process cost can be reduced. This was mentioned by [Cooper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272425/google-scripts-add-multiple-guests-to-a-calendar-event-from-a-single-cell-in-a#comment106613205_60272425) and discussions.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the calendar service of `CalendarApp` is used. In this case, `scheduleClass()` was modified.

#### Modified script:

```
function scheduleClass(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("primary@group.calendar.google.com");
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var [title,,,,startTime,endTime,theDescription,theLocation,,,theGuests] = values[i];
    if(title != "") {
      var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)
        .setLocation(theLocation)
        .setDescription(theDescription);
      theGuests.split(",").forEach(function(e) {event.addGuest(e.trim())});
    }
  }
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Calendar API is used.

#### Modified script:

When you use this script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function scheduleClass(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = "primary@group.calendar.google.com";
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var [title,,,,startTime,endTime,theDescription,theLocation,,,theGuests] = values[i];
    if(title != "") {
      var resource = {
        start: {dateTime: startTime.toISOString()},
        end: {dateTime: endTime.toISOString()},
        summary: title,
        description: theDescription,
        location: theLocation,
        attendees: theGuests.split(",").map(function(e) {return {email: e.trim()}})
      };
      Calendar.Events.insert(resource, calendarId);
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

- Above both modified scripts are the same results.

### References:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [addGuest(email)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addGuest(String))
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike! You've provided two strong solutions to my difficulty. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Drew McAllister Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.